# Some table cells are not displaying

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I ran into a problem at my app today. I have a table inside a View Controller. The problem happens when I tap the `Compare` button. When I tap the compare button, a small animation occurs, every cell is resized to allow a `selected` or `not selected` image to appear.

Here is a video with the problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6SkIbp1xf0E

The problem is that, while all cels should have the default `not selected` button, some cells don't get the image displayed.

Here is a chuck of my code.

```
//animate function
-(void)animate{
[[tableView visibleCells] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(CustomCell *cell, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) 
{   
  [cell.myImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width * 0.15 + 
cell.myImageView.frame.origin.x, cell.myImageView.frame.origin.y + 
cell.frame.size.height * 0.1, cell.myImageView.frame.size.width * 1.25, 
cell.myImageView.frame.size.height * 1.25)];

  completion:^(BOOL finished)
  { 
  // code to execute when the animation finishes
  [UIImageView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
   //select button animation
   cell.compareProduct.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"deselectedProduct.png"];
  cell.compareProduct.hidden = false;
  [cell.compareProduct setAlpha:0];
  [UIImageView beginAnimations:NULL context:nil];
  [UIImageView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
  [cell.compareProduct setAlpha:1];
  [UIImageView commitAnimations];
  }];}
}
```

This chunk of code executes everytime flawlessly. Every cell in I see display the `selected` \ `not selected` button. The problem happens when I scroll.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{           
if (compareActive) //if compare button was pressed
{
[[tableView visibleCells] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(CustomCell *cell, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
CGRect someRect = CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width * 0.15 + 
cell.myImageView.frame.origin.x, cell.myImageView.frame.origin.y + 
cell.frame.size.height * 0.1, cell.myImageView.frame.size.width * 1.25, 
cell.myImageView.frame.size.height * 1.25);
[cell.myImageView setFrame:someRect];

// i was forced to place another moving animation so the user won't notice how the image jumps from the old frame to the new frame
[cell setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.origin.y, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
[cell setFrame:CGRectMake(0, cell.frame.origin.y, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
}];}
}
```

Why some cells don't have the `selected` `not selected` displayed and why the frame jumps? Also, don't forget I am using a CustomCell.

If you have a better solution or other functions to use please point me to them. The feature I want is this: I press the `compare` button, all table cells change their frames at one time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think `[tableView visibleCells]` and `willDisplayCell:` functions aren't a good match.

It's possible that the cell firing `willDisplayCell:` is not returned immediately after when you call `[tableView visibleCells]`.

I guess you should use a bool variable in your ViewController and look at it while reloading your Table View via `cellForViewAtIndexPath:`. And then call `reloadData` when the user clics on your Compare button.